# Is it possible for GHC to determine arity at compile time?

Tags: haskell, ghc

As Haskell encourages currying, many libraries expose high-order constructs. These libraries have no way of knowing the arity of their arguments - I believe that GHC generates code that inspects the arguments at runtime (eval/apply).

Can I inspect and guarantee generation of code that does not check for arity at runtime?

Comment: What are you actually hoping to ensure and/or avoid?

Comment: All functions in Haskell have arity 1... Furthermore Haskell has static typing.

Comment: GHC actually performs two sorts of arity analysis, which it uses to determine when it can safely eta-expand functions. One attempts to determine the inherent arity, that is, the number of arguments that must be applied before the function performs any real work. The other attempts to determine the "call arity" of local function definitions, the minimum number of arguments to which they are actually applied. I could be off on the details.

Comment: This is a good question. If you are asking about what is called `known call` in the paper, then my bet is this is not possible. At least without LTO. But I'm far from expert in these fields.

Comment: A compiler doing that is feasible: one can treat all functions as unary ones, and compile `f x y` with code that first builds the closure `f x` and then applies that to `y`. This is terribly inefficient: the GHC devs statistically observed that most calls pass "all" the arguments in common code. Hence, GHC optimizes for that, generating code that checks is more arguments are available before creating a closure: if "all" are, no closure is generated. This runtime check saves time, overall.